# Idiom for aliasing structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I understand that C is (mostly) call and assign "by value", and that `struct` assignment `a = b` creates a copy of `b`.

This leads to some verbosity when iterating through an array whose members are `struct`, and accessing member fields (example below). Is there an idiom for aliasing structs in a loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N_FOOS 2

struct Foo {
  char *bar;
  char *baz;
};

int main() {
  struct Foo foos[N_FOOS] = {
    {"foo", "bar"},
    {"baz", "qux"},
  };

  for (int i = 0; i < N_FOOS; ++i) {
    printf("foos[%d].bar = %s\n", i, foos[i].bar);
    printf("foos[%d].baz = %s\n", i, foos[i].baz);
  }
}
```

In a higher-level language I would have created an alias within `for` to point to `foos[i]` and avoid repeated indexing.

Would the idiomatic way be to create a pointer that references `foos[i]`?

```
int main() {
  struct Foo *foo;
  struct Foo foos[N_FOOS] = {
    {"foo", "bar"},
    {"baz", "qux"},
  };

  for (int i = 0; i < N_FOOS; ++i) {
    foo = &foos[i];
    printf("foos[%d].bar = %s\n", i, foos[i].bar);
    printf("foos[%d].baz = %s\n", i, foos[i].baz);
    printf("foo->bar = %s\n", foo->bar);
    printf("foo->baz = %s\n", foo->baz);
  }
}
```

The downside is having to do manual deallocation, but I guess that's just an inescapable part of the language.

EDIT: fixed code due to @dbush's feedback

Comment: Unless you turn off almost all optimization, any sane compiler would optimize the common subexpression and won't index twice so it's not something you really have to think that hard about in most cases. The malloc is superfluous and the free is actually an error.

Comment: It might be optimized away by the compiler, but it's still more characters to type (my initial point). This comment would be also better if it explained why `malloc` is superfluous and `free` is an error.

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it, because I don't understand why you used malloc and then freed something other than what you malloc'ed. If you explain your thinking, perhaps it would be easier to talk about where it went wrong.

Comment: Put `struct Foo *foo = &foos[i];` inside the loop, get rid of malloc line.

Comment: You could write hash `define F foos[i]` at start of loop and undef it at the end

Comment: @pvg I was trying to create an alias for `foos[i]` to avoid verbosity with a pointer. You're right that `malloc` is superfluous in this case. I'm actually new to C, so allocating memory for the pointer was probably an incorrect attempt to avoid a null pointer dereference.

Comment: @M.M is there any reason to prefer that over using a pointer?

Comment: Not really , in the old days you might not trust the compiler to optimize out the pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have will work fine.  It can be especially useful if you have a structure several layers deep to abbreviate what you're referring to and make your code more clear.

The one problem you have is a memory leak.  You dynamically assign memory to `foo`, but then you overwrite the address of that allocated memory with the address of another variable:

```
foo = &foos[i];
```

Now the allocated memory is lost.

Because you're using the pointer to point to an existing variable, you don't need dynamic allocation at all.  Get rid of `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: Is what I have idiomatic and is there a better way of creating the alias? Also, regarding `free`, I'm guessing that its behavior would have been undefined if left in, since I passed in a pointer that wasn't created by `malloc` and friends.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer, though @Jesin makes a good point about initializing the pointer explicitly to `NULL`.

Comment: @yangmillstheory it's not a good point to initialize the pointer to NULL -- in fact that would be redundant and may even elicit a compiler warning for unused code. The best option is to not declare the pointer until you are ready to give it its first value (inside the loop)

Answer (score 2):

Your program is incorrect. Here's how to fix it: Remove the `malloc` on the RHS, replace it with `NULL`, and remove the `free` line.

You're just moving the pointer, so there's no need to do manual allocation, and if you `free` the last value, that's a bug because you're `free`ing something that wasn't `malloc`ed.

Comment: The `NULL` assignment isn't technically necessary right?

Comment: It's technically unnecessary, but it's good practice to never leave pointers uninitialized. If you accidentally dereference a null pointer, you get an immediate easily-diagnosed crash, but if you dereference an uninitialized pointer, you might silently corrupt any part of memory and not find out for minutes or weeks depending on the program.

Comment: Thanks. [The reason I called `malloc` in the first place is to prevent a null pointer dereference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320398/idiom-for-aliasing-structs#comment81592277_47320398)

Comment: Thoughts on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47320398/idiom-for-aliasing-structs/47320439?noredirect=1#comment81592809_47320439? You and @M.M seem to be saying directly opposite things.

Comment: @yangmillstheory Because you never use that pointer outside of the loop, M.M is correct that you should not even declare that pointer until inside the loop when you are ready to give it a non-NULL value. The practice of initializing pointers to NULL is really for situations where you need to declare them in an outer block but cannot start pointing them at anything until later. This is not one of those situations.